# Safe connection between Android application and Apache server

Tags: android, database, web-services, networking

Below I explained what I need and in the answer I would like to get information what technology, what kind of protocols, services etc should I use.

Also I know that there is a massive amount of information on the internet, but because there are so many choices I'm unable to make a decision. Here's what I want to have:

1. Android application which will sent and receive information from the internet/server
2. Of course server, which will do some rudimentary computation with the obtained information, then store it and at the end send it back to the client application

I have to admit that the subjects of networking, socketing, protocols, ciphering etc are the ones I've always run away from. Therefore advices such as what domains, databases etc utilize are highly welcome

**Update:** After a bit of a research I've implemented mechanism based on information from this site [1]. I already have a working MySql database with several tables inside. Also I've added php scripts to my Apache webspace and implemented all that's necessary within my Android app.
Now, as I understand communication between php's scripts and MySql database is safe (I've hardcoded the usr/pass within scripts). Therefore the only thing that has left to be done to secure the connection between my Android application and php scripts (I want to prevent the situation when everybody has an access to my php scripts). So my question should be pretty straightforward now, how can it be achieved?

[1] http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/

Comment: Start by reading some tutorials on building client-server android apps. If you run away from learning, well, you won't learn.

Comment: Your question can be summarized as "how should I implement an Android client/server application". You have not provided enough info for us to give you a good answer (and there are many answers for something with so few requirements). What kind of data are you sending? Large images? Text? What kind of computation will the server do? Do you have platform restrictions? Do you have requirements on performance? Are there languages you're familiar with already? Your question is just far too broad and vague.

Comment: @Danra The one who asks learn through the answers. I would more appreciate a valuable link to the tutorial rather than meaningless answer.

Comment: @kabuko Yes true, it is probably too broad. I will have to read some basic stuff first and then eventually ask the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my second question, all the php scripts has been put into directory with the password on my Apache server. To be able to trigger them I need to give this password which is hardcoded in my application. All the connection is done through HTTPS. Now everything works as planned!

Comment: hi could you share a tutorial on how you implemented your i already have a working server and an android app which connect to it. the problem i have though is how do i enable https on both server side an app side. PS. i have already installed a self signed certificate on my server but i don't know if  and how i need to enforce the server to only use https instead of http. Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple TCP/IP connection via [`Socket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)s will do just fine for your purposes.

The lesson (with more information and some examples) from the Java-Docs can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/).

The basic workflow is as follows:

1. Your Android-App opens a `Socket`-connection to your server on a
   given port where a server-application listens.
2. The Android-App sends it's data (whatever that might be) to the
   Server.
3. The Server reads the send data,
4. processes it,
5. stores it...
6. ...then it sends back some response (maybe the computed values) to your
   Android-App.
7. Your app can then figure out if everything went okay and use the
   given data.

Comment: Thanks Lukas, I'll have a look at the 'Sockets' topic